# Where was Victor Zsasz during Gotham season 1 finale?

Tags: gotham

From my understanding, he was a personal bodyguard of Falcone. In the last episode of season 1, first Falcone got hospitalised because of attack on him with rocket launcher, and later people came to kill him in hospital.

If he was bodyguard of Falcone, where was he during whole episode? Why didn't he came to protect him?

Comment: sadly, I don't think there is an explanation for that that exists.  probably was a scheduling conflict with the actor or writers just didn't think about it.

Comment: I think writer just kill him when it suits him. He again disappeared in the scene where penguin mother was killed